# How do I plot geom violin on annual basis from a rasterbrick?

Tags: r

I have 2 raster brick that contains monthly layers of data spanning 30 years i.e. 360 layers. My end goal is to make a violin plot + box plot of the following raster data on an annual basis : 1960-2010.

I have created a dummy code using other solutions here  to achieve the desired output from a random dataset.

```
 set.seed(42)

# Create dummy data
data <- tibble(
  product_id = sample(1:2, 22, replace = TRUE),
  chi_2_ne = runif(22, 0.1, 1.9),
  chi_2_theo = runif(22, 0.1, 1.9)
)

# Use gather to melt the data and reshape it
pdf <- data %>% 
  gather(key = "measure", value = "value", chi_2_ne, chi_2_theo)

# Create the plot
ggplot(pdf, aes(x = factor(product_id), y = value, fill = measure)) +
  introdataviz::geom_split_violin(trim = FALSE, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.2, alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0,linetype=2)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9"), name = "measure") +
  theme_minimal()
```

I want to achieve the same for the raster bricks.
What are the steps I should proceed with assuming a random raster brick? the data I'm using is too large for using dput.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rather depends on the details of your raster bricks. Are they both covering the exact same time periods? Do they both contain strictly consecutive months? How are the layers named?

Assuming you have raster bricks called `r1` and `r2`, and that both cover consecutive months over 30 years (see below), we can do:

```r
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)

d1 <- stackApply(r1, rep(1:30, each = 12), mean) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pivot_longer(everything())

d2 <- stackApply(r2, rep(1:30, each = 12), mean) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pivot_longer(everything())

pdf <- bind_rows(d1, d2, .id = "measure") %>%
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(sub("index_", "", name)) + 1980) %>%
  mutate(measure = c("chi_2_ne", "chi_2_theo")[as.numeric(measure)])

ggplot(pdf, aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = measure, 
                group = interaction(measure, Year))) +
  introdataviz::geom_split_violin(trim = FALSE, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.2, alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0,linetype=2)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9"), name = "measure") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

The visualization looks very nice with two x axis locations, but not so pretty with 30.

---

**Random raster bricks used**

```r
library(raster)

set.seed(42)

r1 <- brick(array(rnorm(12960, seq(1, 2, len = 12960)), dim = c(6, 6, 360),
                 dimnames = list(paste0("x", 1:6),
                                  paste0("y",1:6),
                                  paste(rep(month.abb, 30),
                                        rep(1981:2010, each = 12), sep = "_")
            )))

r2 <- brick(array(rnorm(12960, seq(1, 2, len = 12960)), dim = c(6, 6, 360),
                  dimnames = list(paste0("x", 1:6),
                                  paste0("y",1:6),
                                  paste(rep(month.abb, 30),
                                        rep(1981:2010, each = 12), sep = "_")
                  )))
```

Comment: yes this works perfectly. the data is of consecutive months. Thankyou for your input.